# ForEach Looping over View instead of Chart Data

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

I am trying to get the `ForEach` to populate the data. Obviously this just creates a new view with one dataPoint as expected. How can I inject the array?

I tried `@State` and a `for-in` loop outside of the ViewBuilder but that did not work for some reason.

```
struct DashboardView: View {
    @ObservedObject var scoreListVM = ScoreListViewModel()
    @State private var isPresented = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(scoreListVM.scoreCellViewModels) { scoreListVM in
                    LineView(data: [Double(scoreListVM.score.totalScore)], title: "Acft Scores")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Dashboard")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    self.isPresented.toggle()
                }) {                    
                    Image(systemName: "book.circle")
                        .imageScale(.medium)
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                    InstructionView()
                        .environmentObject(self.colorSchemes)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `ForEach` loop to create many `LineView` items, you can use a dynamic `ForEach` (with explicit `id`):

```
ForEach(scoreListVM.scoreCellViewModels, id:\.self) { scoreCellVM in
    LineView(data: [Double(scoreCellVM.score.totalScore)], title: "Acft Scores")
}
```

Assuming the `scoreListVM.scoreCellViewModels` variable is an array of `ScoreCellViewModel` items.